# date format in php for Date.parse

Tags: php, jquery

I use a custom jquery table called [Datatables](http://datatables.net).  It can automatically sort columns for you.  Apparently it can sort on date as well as long as it is something Date.parse can handle.

I'm having trouble figuring out the format I need that Date.parse can handle.  Currently I generate with php a date with a timezone offset:

```
$mydate=date('Y-m-d g:i A',strtotime($utc)+$timezone_offset*60*60);
```

This will produce output that looks like: `2012-04-07 9:58 AM`.  Datatables doesn't sort this well.  What format can be taken in by Date.parse?

Comment: JS date objects accept a standard unix timestamp in milliseconds, so `var jstime = new Date(<?php echo $mydate = time() . '0000' ?>);` will work nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This format seems to get sorted properly:

```
$mydate = date('d M Y H:i:s',strtotime($utc)+$timezone_offset*60*60);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `U` identifier in date function to get unix timestamp (Seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT))

```
$mydate = date('U', strtotime($utc) + $timezone_offset * 60 * 60);
```

in javascript if you want to use this timestamp then just multiply it with 1000 because javascript date function expects unix timestamp in milliseconds format and PHP uses unix timestamp in seconds format

```
new Date(unixtimestamp * 1000);
```

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for.  I suppose I could edit the javascript with Datatables, but I don't want to do that. There should be a format that Datatables will take and sort successfully.  Thanks for the response.